# JAVA REGEX fine the correct pattern

Tags: java, regex

I tried to use regex. I have this pattern

```
 STACK
 blabla
 OVER
 blabla
 STACK
 vlvlv
 OVER
```

and maybe can another line in the end.
I write this patter that seems to work in sites that check regex but dont work in java.

```
 "^(STACK(\n[^\n]+\n)OVER(\n[^\n]+(\n)?)?)+$"
```

what is the right pattern?
THANKS

Comment: What exacty are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to use match to know if the string that I wrote is in this pattern
The patter is STACK oneLine and then the word OVER and maybe oneline

Comment: please show your java code.

Comment: In java you need to escape twice: once for the string, once for the regex. Try `"^(STACK\\n.+\\nOVER(\\n.+\\n?)?)+$"`. Also, `[^\n]` is `.` (if you don't add `DOTALL` flag)

Comment: Are you sure that your line separator is only `\n` and not `\r` or `\r\n`?

Comment: @Robin In Java's regex engine you can write `\\n` or `\n` to represent line feed. Same about carriage return `\\r` and `\r`.

Comment: Also what are you trying to do? Are you trying to check if entire string contains only such patterns (if this regex matches entire string)? Or maybe you want to find such patterns in your text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to check if your entire input can be matched with regex you can use something like

```
String data =
        "STACK\r\n" + 
        "blabla\r\n" + 
        "OVER\r\n" + 
        "blabla\r\n" + 
        "STACK\r\n" + 
        "vlvlv\r\n" + 
        "OVER";

String regex ="(^STACK$((\r?\n|\r).+(\r?\n|\r))^OVER$((\r?\n|\r).+(\r?\n|\r)?)?+)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

System.out.println(m.matches());
```

- I added `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag to let `^` and `$` be start and end of lines, not like it is by default start and end of entire input.
- Also to say that `START` and `OVER` has to be the only word in line I surrounded it with `^` and `$`.
- Another thing you didn't include in your regex is possibility that line separator can also be `\r\n` or `\r` so I changed it to reflect it.
- Last thing I did was changing `[^\n]` to `.` since they represents almost the same (dot doesn't include `\r` while `[^\n]` does.

Comment: Thanks!! I made mistake and use find and not matches

Comment: Next time try to describe your problem clearer, "dont work in java" is not good problem description. You need to show "how it didn't work", what output you expected and what you got instead. Also include your code attempts. This will let us see faster where problem is instead of having to guess how code which didn't work for you could look like.

Comment: after some games with this I found that this give flase if I have 3 sections of STACK **** OVER **** STACK *** OVER  STACK *** OVER ***

Comment: In your example there is no information that lines between `STACK` and `OVER` are optional. In that case you should use `String regex ="(^STACK$((\r?\n|\r).+(\r?\n|\r))^OVER$((\r?\n|\r).*(\r?\n|\r)?)?)+";` (I changed `.+` to `.*` let you accept empty lines, and removed `+` from `?+` to prevent it from being possessive).